# How to make plots in ggplot R for french character on MAC OS Mojave

Tags: r, ggplot2, encoding, french

I would really be grateful if you can help me out.
I'm not able to show french character, such as "é,è, œ", in plot made with ggplot, while using markdown document for word or html. The outcome plot shows "" or kind of, if I knit the document.
If I only run the chunk, it shows "..." instead of the "é", for instance.
If that can help you, that's my sessioninfo()

```
> sessionInfo() R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit) Running under: macOS  10.14.2
> 
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
> LAPACK:
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
> 
> locale: [1] C 
> [...]
```

I've tried, unsuccessfully the following:

1.Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","French")
2.Sys.setenv(LANG = "fr_FR.UTF-8")
3.Save with encoding "UTF-8"
4.Terminal: defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG fr_FR.UTF-8

The sample of the code is the following:

```
plot.1E <-  ggplot(energy_electrique, 
                   aes(y = Energie_kWh, x = Month, fill = as.factor(Year)))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_manual("Années de mesure",
                    values = c("firebrick1", "forestgreen", "mediumblue", "gold"),
                    labels = c("2015","2016","2017","2018"))
```

Below is the outcome of the code. As you can see, the x axis title has "Ann...es de mesures" instead of "Années de mesures":

[image: outcome]

Comment: Your session information in not really helpful, your ggplot code and a brief sample of the data would provide a better chance of being answered.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the question

Comment: I tried but I can reproduce your problem.  The legend text is printing normally for me.

Comment: Well, which is your MAC system configuration, your R configuration and I don't know what else. I could use your configuration to make my code working.

Comment: I ran this on both a Mac with the latest operating system (R 3.5.2 and ggplot 3.1.0) and on Windows computer, both worked.  I am in the US so system configuration may be a factor.  When I ran `Encoding("Années de mesure")` this returned "latin1".  I do not know if the `enc2utf8` function would help.